# Populating grid and form with same json?

Tags: json, forms, extjs, extjs4

Is it possible to populate grid with some of the JSON data and a form with other, from the same JSON? Two stores or two models or both? simple example... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way to do this would be to manipulate the reader, which as well as returning records, also stores whatever the raw json sent from the server is.

The easiest solution would be to specify the reader parameters for your grid, but then have a listener on the store, which then processed the [rawData](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-property-rawData) property from the reader to get the additional values for your form.

Of course if your form data is related to the grid data, you may do better to rely on nested loading and [form.loadRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord) in the store's load event handler. See the Ext samples (form and grid data binding example) for wasy of doing this.

Depending on the circumstances, another approach similar to the [Ext FAQ](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ_Grid#Load_multiple_stores_with_one_AJAX_request.3F) would be to handle the Ajax through a simple Ext.Ajax.Request, and this process the json through two stores with local proxies, but this doesn't seem quite so Ext4 data model friendly to me.

Comment: Thank you Simon, can you post a simple example of the listener in the store and rawData proprety, i saw the API, but a live example would be nice for the community! Cheers